# Testing a View model in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, testing

I've generated a CRUD operation in entity frame work in MVC4. Now I'm testing that class. I am using the following code in controller for `Details`.

```
   public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Member member = db.Members.Find(id);
        if (member == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(member);
    }
```

And my test code,

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Details()
    {
        MemberController me = new MemberController();
        var mem = new Member();
        int id = 1;
        var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)me.Details(id);
         Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["action"]);
    }
```

While testing it shows,

> Test Failed: Details
>
> Message: Test method SampleTest.MemberTest.Details threw exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.web.Mvc.ViewResult' to >type 'System.Web.mvc.RedirectToRoutResult'

Can anybody please help me to identify the problem?

Comment: That `mem` variable is confusing.

Comment: You appear not to be mocking the Db so maybe `id==1` just produces a Member.

Comment: @Henk:mem is instance of Member model that contains the view models

Comment: And what is it doing in that test method?

Comment: i just want know the controller action is worked or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a `ViewResult` from the action, and try to case it to `RedirectToRoutResult` the test.

---

That has nothing to do with the Entity Framework, but still, I usually avoid using EF objects as the model, for several reasons:

- Difficulty in decorating the classes with attributes (if you are using data annotation)
- Serialization almost always fails: `Member` is an `Employee` who has a `Manager` who have a `Department` which has `Room`s... It never ends.
- Easier to make security mistakes when MVC created and populated your entities after a POST.